# I'm trying to test if a variable does not equal multiple values but I don't want very long code

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, operators

I'm trying to make a `for` loop that ignores lower case vowels. There are 5 in total and I don't want to write 5 'and' statements, because what if I have 10 values I don't want to equal? I would have to write 10 `and`/`or` statements?

Is there a quicker way?

```js
function name(str) {
  let answer = ""
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] !== "a" && str[i] !== "e" && str[i] !== "i" && str[i] !== "o" && str[i] !== "u") {
      answer += str[i]
    }
    return answer
  }
}
```

I don't want to do 5 `&&` operators. Is there a way I can do something simple like this (which doesn't work):

```
if (str[i] !== ("a" && "e" && "i" && "o" && "u") {
  answer += str[i]
} 
return answer
```

I understand how to solve it, I just want to figure out a quicker or easier way to solve it, in case in the future I have 20 values I don't want to = for example. it feels primitive to do 20 && operators

I was expecting for the `!==` to check if `str[i]` was not equal too all the vales in the `()`.

Comment: Put all the values in an array and use `if (!vowels.includes(str[i]))`

Comment: or `/[aeiou]/.test(str[i])`

Comment: If you just want to remove those characters: `return str.replace(/[aeiou]/g, '')`

Comment: please declare `i` as well.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `}`. You're returning on the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: General question - is there a reason everyone is putting all this information in comments instead of answering the question?

Comment: (im sorry im very new to this site, im will attempt to @ you) @Barmar , Thank you ! this solved my problem very quickly. This is so much faster than doing 5 && operators. thank you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I suspect there's a dupe out there and I don't want to incur mickmakusa's wrath if I answer instead of closing.

Comment: @Barmar I apologize for asking a similar question on here, but the similar question to mine, people keep answering with "just use if(i !== a && i !== b) etc." which did not help my problem. So I thought it was better to re-ask that question but more clear and specific to my problem

Comment: @user23333929 I'll bet there are questions where the answers we've given appear. The regexp comments are very specific to comparing single characters in a string, while the array method is more general for matching any set of strings.

Comment: @Barmar I suspected as much, but I think it's time the site changed that policy. It's losing enough visitors already so I think we should be providing answers morereadily than punishing new users. This is probably something better discussed on meta tho.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I agree with the sentiment but duplicate searching is *so incredibly painful* with the SO search mechanism that I usually wait for somebody much more patient than I am to find a dup.

Comment: @Mickmackusa We're talking about you here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Set` to compare against it a character. Also place `return answer` in the end of the function otherwise you break the for loop prematurely on the first character:

```js
function name(str) {
  const vowels = new Set([...'aeiou']);
  let answer = ""
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (!vowels.has(str[i])){
      answer += str[i]
    }
  }
  return answer;
}

console.log(name('asposdiusaeoasi'));
```

Spreading a string into an array and constructing a set is expensive, if you cache it (outside the function) the set solution beats regex:

```
` Chrome/121
----------------------------------------------------------
Set             1.00x  |  x100000  781  782  785  788  799
regex replace   1.63x  |   x10000  127  134  135  136  144
regex           2.37x  |   x10000  185  186  187  189  204
----------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const str = 'asposdiusaeoasi'.repeat(100);

const vowels = new Set([...'aeiou']);
function name(str) {
  let answer = ""
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (!vowels.has(str[i])){
      answer += str[i]
    }
  }
  return answer;
}

const vowelsRegex = /[aeiou]/;
function nameRegex(str) {

  let answer = ""
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (!vowelsRegex.test(str[i])){
      answer += str[i]
    }
  }
  return answer;
}
const vowelsReplace = /[aeiou]/g;
function nameReplace(str) {
  return str.replace(vowelsReplace, '');
}


// @benchmark Set
name(str);

// @benchmark regex
nameRegex(str);

// @benchmark regex replace
nameReplace(str);

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```